# What is this musical symbol?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, jazz, accidentals

[image]

First I thought it was a weird flat sign, but when I played the score it sounded odd. It looks a bit like a natural sign.

Here's the whole measure:

[image]

Comment: The notes partially look like handwritten. Is this the case? If so, could it be the writer's way to write a quarter rest?

Comment: They do look like natural signs, but it is hard to tell out of context. Would natural signs make sense there? Can you post a picture of the whole measure?

Comment: if it's a flat sign, I may have been confused by the shape the composer used in the bass line @Peter

Comment: Who is the composer, and can you get in touch with them?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft definitely not. It's Bernard Herrmann

Comment: OK, well,...  any chance of finding a published copy of the score?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft as far as I know it was never published

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like a handwritten natural sign to me.  The context doesn't suggest any other possibilities

Comment: Strangely, the first natural sign in the lower desk looks different.  But for handwritten, not to mention the resultant harmony,  flat sign is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: I don't think there are any other feasible options!+1. And Bernard knew a thing or two.

Comment: Yep, the only plausible possibility.

Comment: Yes.  I'm surprised there have been other opinions!